# NotificationCenter not receiving posts

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, concurrency

I have a class that accepts accelerometer data and posts it in a notification like so:

```
func notify(accel: accelPoint){

         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("newRawData"), object: nil)
}
```

And two objects set up to observe this, the first being a viewController:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.newRawData), name: Notification.Name("newRawData"), object: nil)
```

Which calls the function:

```
func newRawData(notification: NSNotification){ ...
```

This works just fine.

The other observer is in a regular Swift class, instantiated in the app delegate. (I have tried doing this before and after creating the notifying class):

```
init(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(FilterManager.newRawData), name: Notification.Name("newRawData"), object: nil)

}
```

Which should call the function below but for some reason it does not.

```
@objc func newRawData(){
    print("WHYYY")
}
```

The name this class is correct, and I have seen the the observer is being registered and the notifications are being posted so why isn't this class being notified like the other?

Also, why do I have to expose the `newRawData` function in the second class to objective-C but not the `newRawData` in the `viewController` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you referenced FilterManager class in your AppDelegate? if not add this code in you AppDelegate class. also you  can make FilterManger singleton to solve this problem.

```
var filterManger = FilterManager()
```

Comment: Making the class a singleton seemed to work, but I don't understand why? Could you explain? It seems counter-intuitive that one can only use the notification centre in singletons.